# "Failed to connect to: we.frontend.clouddatahub.net" error while registering Integration Runtime of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[This is what](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell) I followed to setup IR.

In the final step of Registering Azure Data factory self hosted intergration runtime, we need to provide the Authentication Key. then the installation is making a call to internet. Isn't this strange as the VM could be in a private network?

If the VM is not connected to internet and it gets this error then what to do? `"Failed to connect to: we.frontend.clouddatahub.net"`

This is the error I get

```
Failed to execute the command ' -Key xxx'. Error message: Microsoft.DataTransfer.DIAgentClient.HostServiceException: Failed to get service token from ADF service with key xxxx and time cost is: 3.0786307 seconds, the error code is: UnexpectedFault, activityId is: xxx and detailed error message is An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

The issue seems to be disabled remote access. How can I enable it? `Dmgcmd -era 8060` is not working.

I have also a related issue logged [as another VM works and this fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480652/remote-access-issue-in-self-hosted-integration-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have some private network where the communication can go without any restrictions between your data sources and your integration runtime, the integration runtime application needs to be able to communicate with the Azure data factory services as well. Try whitelisting the IPs for your region in the networking settings of your Azure VM or in your firewall - according to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses

Comment: question still remains.. isn't this calling internet?  "we.frontend.clouddatahub.net" . How calling internet is the only option to setup an IR?

Comment: Yes it's calling the internet. If you're going to use data factory with a self hosted integration runtime to access data you have on-prem from the cloud it will have to connect to the internet.